# What is the difference between value=${"Hello"} and .value=${"Hello"} syntax in Lit

Tags: web-component, lit-element, lit

I'm reading the Lit docs, and found that: https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions

```
html`<input .value=${this.itemCount}>`;
```

Testing: I removed the dot before "value" word and nothing changed.

Why I need to add this dot ?

Comment: See the difference between properties and attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot makes it a property, and the other is an attribute.

Attributes only takes in strings. That means if you pass an object, function or array, these will be converted to strings, and then converted back again in the receiving component. This can become quite expensive.

Using properties, your objects, functions and arrays are not parsed, which is why properties (`.myProperty`) are faster.

Comment: Don't recommend one. Recommend them for what they can do. Both have distinct features. If you want to do anything with CSS selectors, properties won't get you anywhere.

Comment: Properties can be used for CSS selectors, though. For example a boolean property: `<button ?my-css-selector=${myProperty}></button`, and in the CSS `button[my-css-selector] {color: red;}`. This will dynamically change the styling a button whenever the property changes